# Error changing column names, names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r

I'm attempting to rename column names in my dataset using this code I found on YaRrr.

This is the YaRrr code:

```
names(df)[1] <- "a"
```

This is my code:

```
names(SF.Data)[1] <- "School Code"
```

I keep getting this error term:

> Error in names(SF.Data)[1] <- "School Code" : 
>     'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

I've tried shortening my string to "School.Code" but this hasn't worked. What's going on?

Comment: What is `names(SF.Data)` ?

Comment: I guess `SF.Data` is a data frame with 0 columns. I use the following code and get the same error message: `x <- data.frame() ; names(x)[1] <- "a"`.

Comment: Ronak SF.Data is my dataframe. Darren, thank you. Somehow my dataframe didn't load so there were no columns.